# Disable jquery in masterpage for a specific content page?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have this code that warns the user about unsaved changes and it's in the MasterPage of the site I'm working on.  I have a search page that doesn't allow the user to save anything and it triggers the unsaved changes warning.  Is there a way to disable the code for this one content page?

```
var _changesMade = false;
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('form').bind($.browser.msie ? 'propertychange' : 'change', function () {
        _changesMade = true;
    });

    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
        if (_changesMade)
            return 'There are unsaved changes which will be lost if you continue.';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude the search form using the [**not** method](http://api.jquery.com/not/).

```
$('form').not('#searchForm').bind($.browser.msie ? 'propertychange' : 'change', function () {
    _changesMade = true;
});
```

Given that the search form has id `searchForm`.

Comment: One caveat: if `form` is defined in a master page, then all pages will have the same form.

Answer (score 0):

Give that page a unique identifier, whether it's a `class` or `id` in the `body` or some element that is unique to that page.

For example:

**HTML**

```
<body class="my_content_page" id="my_content_page">
```

**JS**

```
if(!$('body').is('.my_content_page')) {
    //your code
}
```

or

```
if(!$('body').is('#my_content_page')) {
    //your code
}
```

or any countless ways: `hasClass()`, `$('selector').length`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `ContentPlaceHolder` in the Head of your `MasterPage` so that you will be able to easily add the Scripts resources that you need on those content pages. In this way you could add or not the jquery script on this content page.

Good luck!